# Calculus definite integrals declining word problem

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

The marriage rate in the United States has been declining recently, with about $2.1e^{-0.034t}$ million marriages per year where $t$ is the number of years since 2008. Assuming that this rate continues, find the total number of marriages in the United Stats from 2008 to 2018.

Comment: Dear Cassie: "Welcome to math.SE. Since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. (quoted text by Arturo Magidin.)

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

- Write $2.1\cdot \mathrm e^{-0.034t}$ as $a\cdot b^t$ for some $a$ and $b$.
- If 2008 is year $0$, then 2018 is year $10$.
- $\sum\limits_{t=0}^{10}a\cdot b^t=a\cdot\dfrac{1-b^{11}}{1-b}$.

Answer (score 0):

*This looks like a homework problem.*

**Hint:**

1. Integration of exponential functions: $$\int a e^{bt} dt = a \int e^{bt} dt = \frac{a}{b} e^{bt} + \text{const}.$$
2. Definite integrals: $$\int_{x}^{y} f(t) dt = F(y) - F(x), \text{ where } F'(t)= f(t).$$

Can you take it from here? Can you fill in the values of $a, b, x$ and $y$?